# Time taken by a cubic metal to stop after hitting a wall is independent of the velocity with which it hits the wall!

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, collision, continuum-mechanics

While doodling with stress and strain I came to a conclusion that the time,$t$,take by an object ( here a metallic cube) under elastic collision to stop when hitting a wall (with Young's modulus, $Y_{wall} = \infty $, just for simplicity) is independent($t = \frac {1}{A_0} \sqrt {\frac {mV}{Y}}$)of the initial velocity (assuming that the stress generated during the collision is less than yield strength) 
[image: Stress-Strain curve for metals]
, meaning that the time taken for rebounding ( $= 2t$) is independent of initial velocity,  which is something unexpected. Are there any experimental evidence of such?

Comment: Experimental data on perfectly elastic collisions is probably rare, but the time being independent of velocity should not be unexpected.  You are describing a Hooke's law system and it is well known that the sinusoidal period of a spring is independent of amplitude or velocity.

Comment: That's because the contact time is equal to twice the length of the object divided by the speed of sound in the metal.  This is the time required for a compression wave to travel down the object and for the reflected expansion wave to travel back.  This is when the object loses contact with the wall.